# Soil PH Sensors, Okay? or Snakeoil?

Tags: ph

This is my first post here, I have been wondering if soil PH sensors are real or fake? An example is [Soil Sensor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001229897593.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.32824f68LerWf2&algo_pvid=542ad1a7-2222-48b1-b690-705d6f1d945e&algo_expid=542ad1a7-2222-48b1-b690-705d6f1d945e-0&btsid=0bb0623c16196062048856398e3b2a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_).
After reading through this [post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/21730/how-do-consumer-soil-moisture-sensors-work), these seem pretty useless. However the answers here talk about how USEFUL they are not if they give accurate readings. The thing that worries me about sensors such as these for being placed and left is mainly that it is ONLY reading from ONE place, and this isn't a good representation of the area as a whole.

I am wondering if anyone else has tried these? How accurate (if at all) are these? I am thinking of getting one and testing it against a Home Depot PH paper strip test.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: If you are in the US, you'd be far better off getting a soil sample tested at your state's Extension. Tests are often in the $15-$25 range (depending on how in-depth the results are), with the sample itself consisting of soil from different places in the area you want tested. Along with pH, you'll be told the soil's organic content, potassium and phosphorus needs (if any), and trace elements.

Comment: For pH test only ,the test strips or liquid should be fine . The pH of the soil does not change much so an occasional test is sufficient.  I use aquarium indicator liquid . Mix a spoonful of soil with a spoonful of distilled or deionized ( ie. pure) water . Let it settle/clear then test the pH of the water.